# Why this simple logic doesn't work?

Tags: c++

I just couldn't figure out of why this simple logic in while loop doesn't work.

Basically what the function does is that, it takes an argument and will check in the while loop to see whether if it is not "yes" or "no" then keep looping.

```
void getAnswer(string answer) {

    string newAnswer = "";
    newAnswer = answer;
    while (newAnswer != "Yes" || newAnswer != "yes" || newAnswer != "Y" || newAnswer != "y" || newAnswer != "No" || newAnswer != "no") {
            cout << "Enter yes or no.." << endl;
            cin >> newAnswer;

        }

        if (newAnswer == "Yes" || newAnswer == "yes" || newAnswer == "Y" || newAnswer == "y") {
            chooseOptions();
        } else {
            cout << "Bye See you again " << endl;
            exit(1);
        } 
}
```

But even though I enter "yes" or "no" , it will still looping.

Comment: Change `||` to `&&`.

Comment: why && now I'm really confused. while not yes or not no then keep looping, if "yes" or "no" then break the loop

Comment: I added the explanation as an answer since it doesn't fit in comment.

Comment: if it is yes, it is not no, loop continues.

Comment: `a!=b || a!=c` if `b` and `c` are not the same, is always true, since if the first is false (so `a==b`), the second is true by definition

Comment: If you have two things, everything in the universe is different from at least one of them. This happens easily when you transfer natural language into logic. In ordinary language, "x isn't A or B" means "x is different from *both* A *and* B", not "x is different from *either* A *or* B". (Except if you're in the company of a very annoying programmer who thinks they're being clever for "understanding" logic.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) state that:

```
"not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"
```

Applying this law on your on your condition:

```
newAnswer != "Yes" || newAnswer != "yes" || ...
```

⇔

```
!(newAnswer == "Yes" && newAnswer == "yes" && ...)
```

Now it's easier to see why it's wrong.

If `newAnswer` is something that is not "Yes" or "yes", it'll be evaluated to true, and that's not what you want.

The solution would be changing `||` to `&&`.

Comment: My logic is really bad, im ashamed of myself. How do i practice my logic?

Comment: You shouldn't be ashamed. That's the purpose of leaning and practicing. Keep trying and asking, that's that only way of learning. You're on the right way! I'm still making silly mistakes even after 5 years of programming.

Comment: "How do i practice my logic?" By practicing logic. Experience does the job. If it may help, think to && as "and at the same time ...". You want that the loop breaks when the entered value is "at the same time" different from all the ones you meant. That's the same as saying "at least" (the opposite of "at the same time") equal (the opposite of "different")

Comment: @MarounMaroun: "If newAnswer is something that is not "Yes" or "yes" "...   well ... newAnswer can be anyting (including "Yes" and "yes"), and the && chain will always be false since it  cannot be at the same time equal to different tings

Answer (score 6):

Think about it. I ask you a yes or no question. You tell me "no".

I go down my list, and stop as SOON as I get to a true statement, because that's what logical OR means.

newAnswer != "Yes" >> true. Done. Continue looping.

Fine, you say. This time, you answer "Yes".

newAnswer != "Yes" >> false

newAnswer != "anything else" >> true. Done. Continue looping.

This is a tautology. It's not possible to make that OR condition false. You should use AND.

In your own words, it's not "while not yes or no" but "while not yes AND not no AND not n AND not y..."

Answer (score 2):

Apart the evident inversion between && and || all answer talk about, let me go a little bit further, to make another fallacy evident (not really a bug, but a design weakness): you ask "yes or no" accept anything and if the answer looks-like "yes" you exit. Anything else plays like a no. Even "one cup of coffee".

And inverting all the logic has the same fallacy: check for *N,n,No,no* to decide to don't exit means exit if "tea and biscuits" are answered.

Also, `getAnswer` takes answer and calls `chooseOptions` (which in turn will get some input to give to `getAnswer`): you're not *looping*: you are *recoursing*. And you are doing a same thing (get an answer from an input) from two different places. What does it happen if I want to change `std::cin` with some other stream? Everything to be changed? In how many different places?

A much better logic should force the answer to be consistent.

In your main program you should do most likely something like

```
bool do_exit = false;
while(!do_exit)
{
    //All useful stuff and then ...

    do_exit = getAnswer(std::cin, std::cout, 
      "Do you want to exit? [yes/no]", 
      "please answer yes or no");
}
```

Or, more concisely,

```
for(bool do_exit=false, !do_exit, do_exit=getAnswer(
      "Do you want to exit? [yes/no]", 
          "please answer yes or no") )
{
  //usefull stuff here
}
```

Now, lets get into the answer logic:

You have to get one line of input (not just one word: one line, since I can type "yes, I want"), so `cin>>string` doesn't play well: better `std::get_line`. If it is "yes" return true, if "no" return false and if anything else repeat the reading.

```
bool getAnswer(std::istream& istr, std::ostream& ostr, 
   const std::string& prompt, const std::string& reprompt)
{
  ostr << prompt << std::endl;
  for(;;)
  {
     std::string line;
     std::getline(istr,line);
     if(line == "yes" || line == "Yes" || line == "Y" || line == "y") 
        return true;
     if(line == "no" || line == "No" || line == "N" || line == "n") 
        return false;
     ostr << reprompt << std::end;
  }
}
```

This makes you accept well known "yes or no" variants, but refuse anything else.

Going even furtherly, we can cosider the idea that cin/cout can be other kind of streams, and may be there is no one "typing".

To avoid to go in an infinite loop, we can introduce an attempt limit and throw an exception if it is reached:

```
bool getAnswer(std::istream& istr, std::ostream& ostr, 
   const std::string& prompt, const std::string& reprompt)
{
  ostr << prompt << std::endl;
  for(int attempt=5; attempt>0; --attempt)
  {
     std::string line;
     std::getline(istr,line);
     if(line == "yes" || line == "Yes" || line == "Y" || line == "y") 
        return true;
     if(line == "no" || line == "No" || line == "N" || line == "n") 
        return false;
     if(attempt>1)
       ostr << reprompt << " ("<<attempt-1<<" attempts remaining)"<<std::endl;
  }
  throw std::domain_error("cannot get valid input");
}
```

and let the caller to eventually catch and do some other action, or eventually gracefully terminate.

Furthermore, we can parametrize not just the i/o and the questions, but also the answers, but this is getting too far.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is as follows:

If your string input is a `yes`:

```
newAnswer != "yes"  --> false

newAnswer != "Yes" --> true
newAnswer != "Y" --> true
newAnswer != "y" --> true
newAnswer != "No" --> true 
newAnswer != "no" --> true
```

The logical `or` of several `true`s and one `false` is a `true`. This means that for an input of a `yes` input, the loop will continue.
If you change all those `or`s to `and`s, the logical `and` of several `true`s and one `false` will be `false`. If the input is a `yes` input, the loop will not continue.